# restricting access with nginx

Tags: authentication, nginx

I'm having trouble requiring authorization to use view my site using nginx. I wonder if anyone can help.

I created a password using htpasswd. It created a file called htpasswd which is stored in Conf/ directly next to nginx.conf

The Conf directory is a sibling of `hello_world` and child of the `scta` folder seen below in the listed `root` path.

After restarting the server, my browser asks me for a password. I enter the information, the dialogue box goes away and the browser simply says not authorized. After that, the browser doesn't even give me an opportunity to re-enter my username and password.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE, i realized i'm actually successfully getting through, because when I type in the wrong password I get a 401 error. But when I type in the correct password, I'm moving past the 401 error and instead getting a 403 error.

```
server {
        listen             28005;
        passenger_enabled  on;
        root               /home/me/app/scta/hello_world/public;
        server_name        localhost;
        location / {
            auth_basic "closed site";
                auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
                }

    }

}
```

Comment: Does the page also 403 when you remove basic auth? If so, this is a permissions issue: Nginx cannot access the resources located at `/home/me/app/scta/hello_world/public`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the `remote_user` exists or not, if it exists, it means it is authenicated, so assuming the user is "admin", you would do the following check.

```
server {
    listen             28005;
    passenger_enabled  on;
    root               /home/me/app/scta/hello_world/public;
    server_name        localhost;
    location / {
        auth_basic "closed site";
        auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
        if ($remote_user ~ ^$) { break; }
        set $ok "no";
        if ($remote_user = 'admin') { set $ok "yes"; }
        if ($ok != "yes") {
            return 403;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this, but I'm still having trouble. I'm worried that NGINX is not able to find my password file, can you explain the relation between the different paths listed -- i.e. `root` `location /` and then `conf/htpasswd' I'm unclear how the system knows how to find the relative path `conf/htpasswd'